# How to download a data table in python as pdf while keeping the formatting as desired?

Tags: python, django, pandas, pdf, formatting

I want to download a python data table as a pdf. 
I have tried converting it into an HTML table and then download it. The formatting is not maintained that way. This is possible with js but I need python based solution. Format preview should be able to be viewed in my application( Django or dash). And I would like teh option of changing format templates from my app.
ex:- Selecting blue will make the header of each column blue in color, etc.
Is there any way to converting datatable to pdf without first converting it into HTML.

Comment: What's "python data table"? And could you share a code that you've tried so far?

Comment: I would recommend converting datatable Frame into a pandas dataframe, or into a csv file, or into a plain python list; and then try to create a PDF output from those.

Answer (score 0):

By sending my data frame to from flask to my HTML template I am able to send my dataframe there.
Inside the HTML I am reading the data insidejavascript as {{name|tojason}}.
Using that to recreate a html document and printing that.

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def data_analysis():
    x = pd.read_csv("<filepath>")
    x=x.dropna(how='all')
    x.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return render_template("data_analysis.html",  data=x.to_html(),name=x.to_html())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```